# How to reformat map function output?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.8.

Using the following code:

```
val flattened = avroParsed
  .flatMap(x => x.split(":"))
  .map(y => ((y),1)).reduceByKey(_+_).saveAsTextFile(outputString)
```

I get the output:

```
(p162908907,fb_100004769718383,3)
(p182254724,fb_100006973381466,7)
(p162969164,fb_110762469297799,1)
(p182248948,guest_353470061603278_android,8)
```

How can I modify this so that I get the output as:

```
((p162908907,fb_100004769718383),3)
((p182254724,fb_100006973381466),7)
((p162969164,fb_110762469297799),1)
((p182248948,guest_353470061603278_android),8)
```

The difference is that in the first case the output is a tuple of three elements, while in the second the result is a tuple of two elements, whose first element itself is a tuple of two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your `reduceByKey` is a `Tuple2[String, Int]` and you want a `Tuple2[Tuple2[String, String], Int]`, you'll need an additional `map` which splits the string:

```
val flattened = avroParsed
 .flatMap(x => x.split(":"))
 .map(y => ((y), 1))
 .reduceByKey(_+_)
 .map { case (a, b) => {
    val Array(first, second) = a.split(",")
    ((first, second), b)
  }}
 .saveAsTextFile(outputString)
```

Comment: I get this message when I implement the solution :- "constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : (T1,T2,T3) required : (String, Int)"

Comment: What types are you working with? What is the return type from `reduceByKey`? I need more information to help.

Comment: def reduceByKey(func: (Int, Int) => Int): RDD[(String, Int)]. This is the type for the map function before reduceByKey :- def map[U](f: String => U)(implicit evidence$3: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]

Comment: Would it be helpful if I posted the code of 'avroParsed' as well?

Comment: Your `reduceByKey` returns an `RDD[(String, Int)]`? That doesn't really match what you showed in the question. Is your string delimited by `,`?

Comment: @PixieDev See my updated answer, perhaps that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Yup. You were right. The string was delimited by ' , '